# can not import cv2 in Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)|

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am getting the following error when i try to import cv2. I installed opencv already and its working fine with python but not with Anaconda.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

Comment: have you tried to install it with anaconda? either by the gui or with conda install?

Comment: I installed anaconda with GUI and i also installed pip3 python3

Comment: can you explain by what you mean by: "but not with anaconda"? What code resulted in the above error message? Were you using the anaconda python? with the python that you used, what is the output of running: `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Comment: cv2 can import when i run python3 form Terminal but the problem is i want to import cv2 in Anaconda IDE which i failed to do so.